# How do i get sum to work?

Tags: c, while-loop, sum

I wrote a function to compute and it should also return the sum. However sum is not working fine.
Output:

```
Enter how many  numbers to print : 7
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 
Sum of  series is: 31
```

Sum should be 20

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int num)
{
        int k,count;
        int sum=0;
        int i = 0;  
        int j = 1;
        printf("%d %d ",i,j);
        count = 2; /* count is 2 because we already printed 0 and 1*/
        k = i + j; 
        while(count < num)
        {
            printf("%d ",k);
                            i = j;
                            j = k;
                            k = i+j;
                            sum+=k;
                            count++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("Sum of F series is: %d",sum);

        return;
}
int main()
{
        int num;
        printf("Enter how many numbers to print : ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d",&num);
        f(num);
        return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are not summing what you are printing.

Comment: this sounds like a homework assignment.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes to be done -

**1.** Initialize `sum` to `1` -

```
 int sum=1;    //as you don't include 0 and 1 in loop
```

**2.** Change the position of `sum+=k;` statement -

```
printf("%d ",k);
sum+=k;
```

Because right now in your code -

```
 k = i+j;
 sum+=k;
```

`k` is being changed(*which is incorrect*) before it is added to `sum`, leading to incorrect answer.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ydZxdW)

Comment: Thanks! It is working fine and i also understood why it wasn't working now :)

Comment: @NickM Glad it worked . If you printed the series you will see incorrect series was being generated  :)